# Why PDF is not showing in angular

Tags: django, angular, pdf, x-frame-options

How can I show a pdf file while using a url? Frontend is in `angular` and backend is in `django`. PDF files can have dynamic links but those PDF are hosted on my own server.
I know about X-Frame and `X-Frame` is DENY but I have tried all other options and still unable to fix it. I have tried almost every possible solution available online!!

This is how I am trying to show my PDF in html file

```
<div [innerHTML]="innerHtml"> </div>
```

Here my code which inititalize `innerHtml`

```
constructor(
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {

  }


public setInnerHtml(pdfurl: string) {
    this.innerHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      "<object data='" + pdfurl + "' type='application/pdf' class='embed-responsive-item' style='width: 100%; height: 90vh'>" +
      "Object " + pdfurl + " failed" +
      "</object>");
  }
```

but its showing this error on console and not showing any pdf

```
Refused to display 'FULL_URL_OF_MY_PDF_FILE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Answer (score 1):

install npm i ngx-extended-pdf-viewer --save

angular.json

```
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": []
```

in html :

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'assets/example.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true"height="80vh"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

I hope this is help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `<iframe [src]="{{pdfUrl}}"></iframe>`. this is a hack, but it solve the problem.
2. This NPM packege is useful

> `npm i ng2-pdf-viewer` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer